# Adding a reverse jquery animation when rolloff

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make the title animate down when you rolloff the hit area. You will notice its currently working on rollover, title animates up 20px, so basically when you rolloff the title should return to its starting position.

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aGcpR/10/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumb">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="copy">
             <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.content').hide().removeClass('content').addClass('content-js');

$('.thumb').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.content-js').fadeToggle();
    $('.copy h1').animate({'margin-top':'0px'});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add another animation in the `.hover()` (which takes two parameters : mouse enter and mouse leave)

http://jsfiddle.net/aGcpR/12/

Comment: Actually the two parameters are `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.. not mouse over and mouse out. >> _The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events_ << from docs

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `hover()` shortcut, use mouseenter / mouseleave, and put everything in one single function :

```
$('.content').hide().removeClass('content').addClass('content-js');

$('.thumb').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    var dir = e.type == 'mouseenter';
    $(this).find('.content-js').fadeToggle();
    $('.copy h1').animate({'margin-top': (dir ? 0 : 20)});
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aGcpR/13/)

Comment: Adding stop() to avoid unexpected animation behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/aGcpR/14/

Answer (score 0):

lots of ways to do this. here is my solution:

give .content a display of none so we don't have to do it with javascript:

```
    .content {
        display: none;
    }
```

modify the javascript to use mouseenter and mouseleave with on and catch elements in variables:

```
    var $thumb = $(".thumb");
    var $jsContent = $(".content");
    var $copyHeader = $jsContent.find(".copy h1");

    $thumb.on("mouseenter", function () {
        $jsContent.fadeIn();
        $copyHeader.animate({"margin-top":"0px"});
    });

    $thumb.on("mouseleave", function () {
        $jsContent.fadeOut();
        $copyHeader.animate({"margin-top":"20px"});
    });
```